# Grid of buttons in Unity - button bounds are stretching beyond their visuals, capturing clicks meant for other buttons

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am using unity UI for the first time and trying to create a level selection menu just like Angry Birds.

I had successfully created the dynamic level selection menu. It was all good in the inspector but when I build and run it, something strange happens: when I click on the first button of the first row, instead of that button, the last button of that row got clicked.

I searched and found that the image was not stretching (because of preserve aspect property checked) but the bounds were stretching with the resolution so the bounds were overlaping and the wrong button was getting clicked.

1. There is a panel which is child of the canvas gameObject.
2. Buttons are child of panel gameObject.
3. Panel's anchors are set to stretch the canvas.
4. Buttons' anchors are set to stretch the panel.

Here is the code to create menu dynamically.

```
public class UITest : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Button button;
    public RectTransform parent;

    void Start()
    {
        SetupButtons();
    }


    void SetupButtons()
    {
        float x = -155;
        float y = 55;

        for(int i=1; i<15; i++)
        {
            var I = i;
            var btn = Instantiate(button) as Button;
            var btnRect = btn.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

            float width = btnRect.rect.width/5;
            float height = btnRect.rect.height/5;

            btn.transform.SetParent(parent, false);
            btnRect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
            btn.onClick.AddListener(() => Temp(btn, I));

            if(i%5 == 0)
            {
                y += (height);
                x = -155f;
            }

            else
            {
                x += -width;
            }

            //Debug.Log(width +", " + height);
        }
    }

    void Temp(Button btn, int i)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Clicked: " + i);
        Debug.Log(btn.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition + " " + btn.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect);
    }
}
```

Here are some screenshots to better understand the problem.

I hope you guys have understood the problem please help me solve the problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Quite frankly, you would be better off not using Unity UI for a menu like this.

Comment: yeah I read it before there are some performance issues with this but I don't want spend another day to learn new tool.

Comment: Not new tools, just use GameObjects instead of UI canvas for all of this.  Unity UI does some stuff well, but a menu screen like this, I would suggest you do not use it at all.  That is just my opinion.

Comment: Hmm I will try that tomorrow but if you can help me with that?

Comment: Help you with trying tomorrow?

Comment: no, help me with this problem.

Comment: I kinda just did :P   In all honestly, the unity UI anchoring system is a tinkering nightmare.  With a screen like this, it is going to be very difficult to anchor all those buttons in a way that will work nicely with Unity UI.

Comment: yeah you are write this really is painful but after some time working with this system I started to feel it is not that painful, I had solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
transform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
transform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1f, 1f);
transform.pivot = new Vector2(.5f, .5f);
```

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1007886/how-to-set-the-new-unity-ui-rect-transform-anchor.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already know how to set anchor points through code, anyway I had solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the response but I had solved the problem myself.
In case anyone else facing this problem, I just set the anchor points to be the middle of the panel and my problem vanished.